# RequestMapping discriminating by user in Spring

Tags: spring, request

I have two controllers that handle the same resource. One for the regular web app and another one for portals (and in theory there could be more than one portal and more controllers).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/web/cases")
public class CasesDetailController extends BaseController<CasesForm> { ... }

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/portal/cases")
public class CasesPortalDetailController extends BaseController<CasesForm> { ... }
```

In some controllers we just resolve a different view for the portal, but for some cases the controller logic is quite different. For example this one has many mappings in the portal that are not available in the app.

The problem comes with managing 2 different urls for the same resource. For example, if I wanna place a link for a case I have to calculate it in the server by checking if the current user is logged in the web or the portal instead of placing a constant base url and an uuid as parameter.

My question is if I can do something about the request mapping to decide which controller can I use. The best I can think of is using a parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/cases") // Web
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/cases", params = "device=portal") // Portal
```

But I would like to avoid sending that info in the url when I have it available in the user (we use a custom user class that extends the base user from spring and it contains the device). Is there any way to check that in the request mapping? Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*/cases", magicFunctionality=getLoggedUser().getDevice()="web")
```

Probably nothing like this exists (at least I found nothing in the manual) but any ideas of how to face this problem would be wellcome.

Thanks in advance.
Gonzalo.